# Multivariate martingale and tensor-product sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional stochastic process. Suppose that $\forall i \leq n$, there exists a measure $\mathbb{P}^{(i)}$ such that the component $M^{(i)}$ is a $\mathbb{P}^{(i)}$-martingale. Is it true that $M$ is a $\otimes_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}^{(i)}$-martingale ?

I would tend to say yes, as a multivariate process is a martingale if and only if each component of this process is a martingale, but I am not completely sure as I consider a different probability measure for each component.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I do not understand why you use a product measure $\otimes_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}^{(i)}$ to express that $M$ is a martingale. It is more important to clearly specify the filtrations. For an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$ every component $B^{(i)}_t$ is an $({\cal F}_t)$-martingale where that filtration is generated by all components. This has to do with independence of the components. The probability space $(\Omega,{\cal A},\mathbb P)$ is the same for all components.